# How can I completely overlap a picture? And it doesn't align to the left

Tags: html, css

It's a strange position when you overlap the picture.

```
<img id = "ganttIn" src = 'ganttBackground.png'><br>
<div id = 'chartBar0' style = '
            float:left;
            position : absolute;

            width : 10%;
            height : 20px;

            background-color : #D4F4FA;

            display : inline-block;
            '>
<\div>
<\img>
```

I want

```
#ganttIn{
  position: relative;
  top : 20px;
  left : 40px;
  /*margin: 20px auto 40px auto;*/

  width : 80%;
  height : 25px;
  z-index: 1;

  text-align: left;
}
```

I want to make two pictures superimposed into a gantt chart. That's why Bar wants to align to the left. But #chartBar is a central alignment, not a left-hand alignment It also has a strange location #chartBar is slightly downwards rather than overlaps with the illustration. Can I see why this is happening?

Comment: first of all your html syntax is incorrect, you don't end the tags that way... should be `<div> ... </div>`, not `<div> ... <\div>` and working example would be nice

Comment: I'm sorry. That's a typo. I actually finished with</div>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick fix. Not sure if this is what you really want though.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="ganttIn" src="ganttBackground.png"/>
    <div id="chartBar0"></div>
</div>
```

css (add the `z-index: 2;` to the one you need on top)

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    top : 20px;
}
#ganttIn{
    position: absolute;
    /*left: 40px;*/ enble this if you need
    width: 80%;
    height: 25px;
}
#chartBar0{
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #D4F4FA;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Positioning has been resolved, but z-index : setting 2 to the img tag does not overlap on the ganttBar
Do you have any idea why this is happening?
Also, I want to make ganttchart. Therefore, I want to list many ganttBar in GanttIn.